# how to use setProperty in FUSE ESB

Tags: xml, xpath, jboss, apache-camel, fuseesb

### I have following XML:

```
<sam:Order>
   <Order1>
   <OrderNo>12345</OrderNo>
    <OrderDate>13-08-2015</OrderDate>
    <OrderMode>online</OrderMode>
    </Order1>
 </sam:Order>
```

### My Camel route:

```
  <setProperty propertyName="IncomingSoapMessage">
                <xpath  xmlns:sam="http://Order.com/">/sam:Order</xpath>
  </setProperty>
  use enrich/split.... some any components....      

  <log message="${body}"/>
```

So, is it right way to use setProperty. The property "IncomingSoapMessage" must have following XML

```
<Order1>
<OrderNo>12345</OrderNo>
<OrderDate>13-08-2015</OrderDate>
<OrderMode>online<OrderMode>
</Order1>
```

Also this property should be the current message in context(in simple words it should be the payload). i.e; when i log message using ${body}, i should be able to see XML as

```
   <Order1>.....</Order1>
```

Please suggest me the solution to this!!! In case of any clarification pls comment..

Comment: Pls do answer. Suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think he asking for logic to retrieve child elements from XML and keep it in the flow.

```
<sam:Order>
    <Order1>
        <OrderNo>12345</OrderNo>
        <OrderDate>13-08-2015</OrderDate>
        <OrderMode>online</OrderMode>
    </Order1>
</sam:Order>
```

This to be modified as:

```
<Order1>
    <OrderNo>12345</OrderNo>
    <OrderDate>13-08-2015</OrderDate>
    <OrderMode>online</OrderMode>
</Order1>
```

and sent for further camel components.

Comment: try using xpath as
  <xpath  xmlns:sam="http://Order.com/">/sam:Order/node()</xpath>